# Can EF5 works fine in event based processing

Tags: c#, .net, performance, entity-framework

I have this code for example for an event handler

```
public void ONDataArrived ( string data ) 
{
//do some processing and save it to DB using EF 
ctx.Add ( x ) ; 
ctx.SaveChanges ()  ; 

}
```

Is there any chance that EF may error if this event fired a couple of times in the same time ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF 5 can work in several different models, depending on how you want to use it. There are templates for using context-tracked entities, self-tracked entities, or POCOs. For your case, I would recommend not keeping your context object around. Self-tracking entities are probably what you're looking for - they store internally all of the information needed to update the database instead of relying on the context to track it.

If you go the self-tracked route, then your OnDataArrived method would just create a new context object and update the entity, which would also address the threading issue mentioned by weismat.

Comment: Using self-tracking entities wont solve concurrency issues which can happen in multi-thread environment.

Comment: Self-tracking entities resolve this problem because the context does not have to be kept open. A context is open only for the scope of persisting the entity, then closed. Since you don't need to persist a context across calls, you don't have to worry about multiple threads accessing it at the same time.

Comment: Self-tracking entities will work as long as it is guaranteed that the events work on different entities.

Answer (score 1):

The context objects from the Entity Framework are not threadsafe - thus it will break.
You will need to synchronize the Context in case events will be processed in parallel.

Comment: I am running this in one application (single thread ) , is it possible that events in single thread to run in parallel?  let say I didnt add any async code

Comment: I agree with Tim that you should look at a different model.
A single application can have multiple threads and sometimes threads/tasks create threads implicitly.